# select from list not containing particular item in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have two class.

```
public class Category
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public List<Category> ProductCategory {get;set;}
}
```

Now i have Category list based on that i need to get product

```
List<string> filtercategory ={"HomeMade","Uncooked"}.
```

I need to all Products which doesn't belong to 'HomeMade' and 'Uncooked'.

What should be linq query logic on this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter with `Where`:

```
List<Product> productList = GetProducts();
var filteredProducts = productList
                         .Where(p => p.ProductCategory
                                      .All(pc => !filtercategory.Contains(pc.Name)))
                         .ToList();
```

This filters the `productList` and takes only those products for which *all* category names are *not contained* in `filtercategory`.

---

*I only tested this in linq-to-sql, not with entities, so I'm not 100% sure that this also works for entities*.

Comment: Rene Vogt : Thanks a ton. Works correctly.  Just one edit you can do. Put one more bracket like `(pc.Name))).ToList()`